# Postgres jsonb_path_query to filter sub-arrays by their length

Tags: postgresql, json-path-expression

In Postgres 13.3, I'd like to extract sub-arrays of a particular length from a `jsonb` value:

```sql
select jsonb_path_query('[[0,1], [0,1,2]]'::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.size() >= 3)');
```

However, this returns nothing (0 rows).

What am I doing wrong?
Note that I'd like to keep using `jsonpath` - while this example is simplified, the real case is much more involved and relies on the flexibility of jsonpath expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The `$[*]` will execute each element within your array's array at the time, so evaluates separately `0`,`1`,`0`,`1`,`2`

The following does the trick

```
select jsonb_path_query('[[0,1], [0,1,2]]'::jsonb, '$ ? (@.size() >= 3)');
```

result

```
 jsonb_path_query 
------------------
 [0, 1, 2]
(1 row)
```

Comment: An alternative approach I just found is to use `strict` mode, so that the sub-arrays are not expanded automatically: `strict $[*] ? (...)`.